# Website is not accepting my android application

Tags: android, xml

The website http://www.slideme.org is not accepting to upload my android project. It says that the manifest file must have a label. I m posting my manifest file it does have a label.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="android.com.machineInfo" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".machineInfo" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
</manifest>
```

Moreover when I change android:label="@string/app_name" to android:label="Machine Information" it accepts the label and shows error that your app must have an icon. plzz help. My app is working fine on emulator

Comment: (I'm not an Android programmer, so I'll just comment...) I'm guessing that anything that starts with `@` is supposed to be replaced by something meaningful.

Comment: strings are already stored in string.xml. They have to be started from '@' sign. Moreover i have already written that the app is working perfectly in the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mailing to the site helpdesk I came to know they don't support Android 2.2. So, finally I compiled my application again on Android 2.1 platform and it got uploaded. You can see my apps here: https://slideme.org/user/vaibhavpandey

Answer (score 0):

Check your @drawable/icon path. Every app should have app_name stored into strings resource and their own icon which should be stored into drawable folder. Check if it exist. Probably you are using standard icon which can be not required and you should to add your own icon to project. 
Anyway I recommend to read [about manifest file](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)